# FlashDevelop ? Do i still need Flash CS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I am fairly new to Flash and AS3.

My questions is do I actually still need to use Flash CS6 to setup the stage and library files.

Or can it all be done from FlashDevelop ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it if you want to create graphic objects to use them later in your code. The alternative is to create everything by code

Comment: You don't **need** it to create graphic objects. As you are still free to create graphics in another app and then add to your Actionscript project via [Embed] metadata.

Comment: Right. But flash gives you the possibility of build structured objects with instance names, export them as classes and control them via code. But you're right

Comment: Sure thing, I just wanted to highlight and dispel the myth that you need to pay for commercial software in order to create engaging Flash content. In the same way as creating HTML-based content, the entire workflow can be free of charge :)

Answer (score 1):

Few months ago I switched completely to FD and since today I successfully built everything only in FD. The reason was that I had huge project to publish, and I couldn't compile it in Flash because of memory shortage for JVM compiler. With FD that was not a problem.

So in short, no, you don't need flash any more.

Though maybe there can be some things that you can create quicker and easier way in Flash than in FD (for example: some timeline animation and then publish to SWC to use with FD).

I still have Flash installed, just in case for quick animation jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Flash CS6 is an application similar to Photoshop, you generally use it for creating/structuring/positioning graphical resources and then makes it possible to animate these (from keyframe to keyframe) and then access the graphical content from code.

So, the answer is no, you can create a SWF file without Flash, you can embed content to use in AS3-code without flash and you can use flex-components and position them without flash.

But creating any bigger project like that would be pretty unnecessary since you just as well could use some other language or tools for doing that kind of stuff. Tools and languages that were designed to do this specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you need to use vector graphics, drawn in Flash, then the easiest way to incorporate them in your project is to use the IDE-based project (http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Projects#AS3_Flash_IDE_Project). This isn't the only way, but it's easier than packaging them up and using libraries. In this case you are effectively using FD just as an external AS editor (and it's worth doing it just for this, since it is a *much* better editor than the one built in to Flash Pro.

If, on the other hand, you are working with objects drawn in code, with text, or with external bitmaps, then no, there's no real need to use CS* at all.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage to OOP is having an environment like Flash for layout. It's been pretty crucial for me as a designer and when implemented correctly with a proper class structure, becomes extremely powerful. It really depends on what you are using as3 for. I find the Flash architecture to be most advantageous in the context of interface design, but for things like games or "static" interactives, sometimes its much more efficient to do everything in code and compile outside of Flash.